# pdf generation with arabic content -not display arabic content

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I try to generate a document  visualforce page with both english and arabic content. in our browsers, we can see both languages, however the generated PDF only contains the english content, whereas the arabic content is empty.

please any body hlep me

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some code for us to reproduce? Its best way to get proper support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PDF file fails to display all the page’s text, particularly multibyte characters such as Japanese or accented international characters, adjust your CSS to use a font that supports them. For example:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" renderAs="pdf">
<head>
    <style>
        body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }
    </style> 
</head>
<body>

これはサンプルページです。<br/>
This is a sample page: API version 28.0

</body>
</apex:page>
```

“Arial Unicode MS” is the only font supported for extended character sets that include multibyte characters.

Please also refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm

Best