# Visualforce render as pdf doesn't render arabic content

Tags: visualforce, pdf, language

We are trying to render a VF page as pdf using `visualforce render as pdf` in arabic language.

Except for the english text below none of the other text appear in the pdf especially the one in arabic in p tag below.

[image]

There is already another question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205688/pdf-generation-with-arabic-content-not-display-arabic-content) raised yesterday but it doesnt contain the VF code so created a new question.

We followed this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm) in salesforce documentation for VF render as pdf but it doesnt work

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false"  renderAs="pdf">
<head>
    <style>
        body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }
    </style> 
</head>
<body>

これはサンプルページです。<br/>
This is a sample page: API version 28.0
 <p>
     مرحبا    </p>
<p>

    </p>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000beQ4AAI) created for it to be enabled in future.

Is there any other solution we can try to get around this? for now the only work around we have is to render the page as Visualforce and use the browser print functionality.

**Update:**

Based on the suggestion provided in the comments by kurunve i tried it and it seemed to print the Arabic content but not the correct content though

I tested the same page with Visualforce render as PDF and just Visualforce page the results are different

***Visualforce render as pdf:***

[image]

***Visualforce Page without render as pdf:***

[image]

Confused that same content with and without the renderas tag behaves differently. Any insights on why it behaves this way would be appreciated.

Comment: <body style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; font-size: 14pt; "> works :)

Comment: Thanks @kurunve. Updated the question. with and without renderas tag VF page prints different content

Comment: Try upgrading the API version for visualforce

Comment: @RahulSharma: tried with 42 just that the content inside says 28. The results are the same.

Comment: It looks like a RTL-LTR problem. Salesforce RTL support is abysmal. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_getstart_rtl.htm&type=5

Comment: Had a similar problem with locales, try upgrading to the latest api version (51.0)